# how to use ternary operator(?:) with break keyword

Tags: c#, break, ternary-operator

I tried to use ***"break" with ternary operator(?:)***  the way that if-else works. it gives compilation error.

Error

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement`

```
Status s10 = null;
foreach (var item in DeviceStatusList)
{
    s10 = item != null ? (Status)(item.Value as List<Status>).Where(x => x.Field.ToString() == "Safe Door").SingleOrDefault() && break: new Status { Field = "", Value = "" };  
}
```

Comment: "How?" Not at all. The ternary operator must return exactly one single value. So what exactly are you trying to achieve here? What is your *actual* problem, of which you think this may be the solution - which itn apparently is *not*. Apart from this notice, that `Where` doesn´t *modify* your list, but *returns* a new one.

Comment: It's not clear what you expect `someExpression && break` to mean. Are you trying to assign a value to the variable and then break? If so, that's really not what `&&` is intended for

Comment: Try this without break:

`(Status)(item.Value as List<Status>).SingleOrDefault()(x =>x.Field.ToString() == "Safe Door")`

Comment: Just a side note, ditch the ternary operator all together. It is not really readable for a new person who might have to deal with this code.